# Capture image when conditions are met

Tags: android, android-camera

Greeting all,

I am developing an app and I need to capture images when certain conditions are met. So far, I have a SurfaceView previewing the back-facing camera, and all my conditions are done. I would like to have the camera take the photo when some conditions are met. There will be more than one photo taken while the user is using the app. So the preview will continue till all the conditions are met. Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks!

**SOLUTION**:
I found some of this code and worked on it.

```
Camera.ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
      // TODO bl
    }
  };

  PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback() {

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
  };
  PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/ImagesFromCamera");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 
            //Unix time stamp for unique file naming. 
            long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L; 
            String fileName = "image"+ unixTime +".jpg";
            File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Notify the user when the image is taken. 
                Toast.makeText(CustomCameraActivity.this, 
                        "Image saved.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Continue the Preview as it will stop once an image is taken.  
            camera.startPreview();
            }
    };

            //Will call the camera to take a photo.
        camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code and at least get an idea of your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point you need to call `takePicture()` on the camera when the condition is met.  Then `startPreview()` in the first line of the `onPictureTaken()` callback that you will have to provide in order for the camera to continue.

When all conditions are met, also be sure to `release()` the camera before leaving within your `onPause()` of the Activity that uses the camera.  As this could cause problems for yourself on other loads of the app or other programs.

Comment: Thank you for the help even though my question wasn't super clear. It actually steered me in the right direction. I have posted the code I used above for those looking for help.